# Search functionality in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

In my C# app I am showing order list in a table. The url to that page is

```
/Organization/Orders/id
```

id in this case is organization id. My controller looks like this

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Orders(String id)
    {
        Organization org = Organization.Get(id);
        ViewBag.Orders = org.GetOrders(50).ToList();
        return View(org);
    }
```

Now I am trying to implement a search functionality in there. In the view I have a search form going on. When the user hits the search button I take him to this controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Orders(String orgId, OrderSearch os)
    {
        Organization org = Organization.Get(orgId);
        ViewBag.Orders = org.GetOrders(50).Where(i => i.GetLocation().FriendlyName.Contains(os.FriendlyName)).ToList();
        return View(org);
    }
```

The issue with this approach is that, if the user search for a particular location name it will take him to the Post method. It will work fine but lets assume that the user refreshes the browser it will still show the searched content rather than the reset the search.

I understand it is because I am in the post method and in the post parameters I would have locationName.

So, is there any other good way to do implement search?

Comment: Make your form a GET, and change the method to `[HttpGet]`

Comment: You may find [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33154580/3110834) helpful.

Comment: It won't work, I have tried that. The issue is that it be ambiguous between the two functions. Which one to call.

Comment: @RezaAghaei how should I be calling it from client? I mean what would be the form look like?

Comment: Using a form you can post/get the request to that action like other actions.

Comment: The `foreach` loop is not actually needed, you can do `orders = org.GetOrders(50).Where(i => i.GetLocation().FriendlyName.Contains(locationName)).ToList();`

Comment: @RezaAghaei the issue that I still would have is where would be the "orgId" go? The parameter I am passing to get organization?

Comment: It would be in `OrganizationSearchModel`.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Not necessarily needed, the URL could simply change to `/Organization/Orders/id?locationName=xxx` or perhaps with a routing change `/Organization/Orders/id/xxx`

Comment: Can I please get a code snippet?

Comment: @DavidG the solution doesn't have any conflict with routing.It simply uses `Model Binding` and works with each `Route` you prefer to use. It also works with `GET`and `POST` and have no limit working with both of them.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I know, I was just pointing out that you don't need a view model just for this, it can be done entirely over the URL.

Comment: @RezaAghaei now I am using the search model that you mentioned. The issue is still the same. I am on a page getting list of all the orders. I then search for a particular location. I get the redefined result list. Now I refresh the browser but I still get the filtered result. I still have two actions one with searchModel other the simple one. Will edit my question so that you can see.

Comment: @DavidG Putting all values in url or in a post is not related to that model. The model is for getting data from view and passing to business logic. Also using that model is only a part of that solution to have an organized application :)

Comment: @ChaudhryMohsinAli Using that approach makes your application more clean and more flexible and answers **So, is there any other good way to do implement search?**

Comment: @ChaudhryMohsinAli But about refresh problem. When you refresh a page using **f5** in case of **using `Get`** obviously search values will deliver to your action, because they are in url.  When you refresh a page using **f5** in case of using **using `Post`** browser doesn't automatically send post parameters.

Comment: @RezaAghaei thanks for the better approach. My code is much cleaner now. But the issue I am having is with the refresh one. My second action is Post and still I get those parameters.

Comment: Dear @ChaudhryMohsinAli did you read my previous comment? What you expect from **f5**?

Comment: @RezaAghaei now I get. :)