# The parameter dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'IDnumber' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

So i am building a book search page and everything else works (search by title, author etc) but I cant figure out how to search by the unique number which is an int in our db -- I've tried several things like converting to int32, turning IDnumber into a string etc but still cant find a solution

parameters:

```
public ActionResult Index(int IDnumber, string LnameString, string FnameString, string bookGenre,string searchString)
{
    //LINQ  query to select books
    var books = from m in db.Book
                select m;
    //ID Number
    if (IDnumber != null)
    /* the if statement gives the following warning which i cannot resolve: the result of the expression is always 'true' since a value of type 'int' is never equal to null of type int?*/
    {
        books = books.Where(x => x.BookID == IDnumber);
    }
...
}
```

View code:

```
<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Books")){
<p>
    Genre: @Html.DropDownList("bookGenre", "All")
    Title: @Html.TextBox("SearchString") <br />
    Author First Name: @Html.TextBox("FnameString")
    Author Last Name: @Html.TextBox("LnameString") <br />
    ID Number: @Html.TextBox("IDNumber")
    <input type="submit" value="Filter" /> 
</p>
}
```

Exact error:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter
>   'IDnumber' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(Int32, System.String,
>   System.String, System.String, System.String)' in
>   'SafariBooksGroup15.Controllers.BooksController'. An optional
>   parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as
>   an optional parameter. Parameter name: parameters

Comment: books = books.Where(x => x.BookID == Convert.ToInt32(IDnumber)); should just be  books = books.Where(x => x.BookID == IDnumber) shouldn't it?

Comment: Oh you are correct, i'll edit sorry

Comment: `IDnumber is already of type int` no need to do any converting on that.. take the time to read / debug your code

Comment: you can use `int?` for `IDnumber` and include it in search if it has value.

Comment: @MethodMan Ya sorry that didnt make sense there, however fixing it still doesnt address the issue

Comment: @RezaAghaei could you please elaborate on how and where to do this?

Comment: @Parth, change the parameter in the method definition of Index to be an int? instead of an int object

Comment: @Parth Yes, see the answer below

Comment: @RezaAghaei i gotchu!! sorry we immediately went back to coding :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `int?` for `IDnumber` and include it in search if it has value.

```
public ActionResult Index(int? IDnumber, string LnameString, string FnameString, string bookGenre,string searchString)
{
    //LINQ  query to select books
    var books = from m in db.Book
                select m;
    //ID Number
    if (IDnumber.HasValue)
    {
        books = books.Where(x => x.BookID == IDnumber.Value);
    }
...
}
```

---

Also if you are looking for a simple and extensible pattern for search, I recommend you to separate concerns and use a business logic class and a search model to have an action method like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(BookSearchModel searchModel)
{
    var business = new BookBusinessLogic();
    var model = business.GetBooks(searchModel);
    return View(model);
}
```

The answer below describes and implements such pattern:

- [Filter/Search using Multiple Fields - ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33154580/3110834)

Comment: wow...such a simple fix for something that was really perplexing me..thanks alot!!!

Comment: If you are looking for a good pattern for search, you may find my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33154580/3110834) helpful :)