# While filtering, how to POST a SearchModel, but GET a different ResultsModel back in the view

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor, filter, view

I am creating a filter view to find records. This example on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34343635/6085193) helps, but does not mention how handle the (Filtered) `View`.

The err below is because, the actions returns a `List<ProductViewModel>`, and it Errors/complains that the View is using a `SearchViewModel,` I need to this `POST` the searchmodel/variables, but`GET` back the list/results model

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ViewModels.ProductVM]', but this
>   dictionary requires a model item of type 'ViewModels.SearchModel'.

Issue/Question: **Since there are two models**, the `SearchViewModel` passed to the controller & the `ProductViewModel` returned as a result, **which model should be strongly typed to the view? and How can I create the view to handle both `SearchModel` & `ProductModel`** *If I stronglyType ProductVM, then I loose the submitform from the SearchVM.*

I create the `SearchView` as the mainview, & the `_ResultsPartialView` as a partialView, is this wrong?

```
public ActionResult Index(SearchModel searchModel)
{
    var filteredProdVMList = _Repository.GetFilteredProducts(searchModel);
    return View(filteredProdVMList);
}

public class ProductVM
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // implicit const... blah.. removed
}

public class SearchModel
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public int? PriceFrom { get; set; }
    public int? PriceTo { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `SearchModel` needs to contain a property `IEnumerable<ProductVM>`, and you view uses `@model SearchModel` (and you probably should be making a GET, rather than a POST when you submit)

Comment: I compsed a new VM with `List<ProductVM>` & `SearchModelVM` ..  I got this erro.. _The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ViewModels.ProductVM]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type `ViewModels.Search..VM'._

Comment: To understand that error, refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40373595/the-model-item-passed-into-the-dictionary-is-of-type-but-this-dictionary-requ). But you did not seem to understand my first comment. Your existing `SearchModel` just needs an additional property `public IEnumerable<ProductVM> Products { get; set; }` and you return just `SearchModel` back to your view (and populate `Products` based on the filters and use a `foreach(var product in Model.Products)` in the view

Comment: You have not shown the view or the other controller method so hard to give a concise answer

Comment: @StephenMuecke I added the view code.. cleared out some of the extra stuff. While searching I saw previous answer where you were appending invoices... but I keep getting the error above.

Comment: The only controller method you have shown is `Index()` which is for an `Index.cshtml` view (is that the view you have shown?).

Comment: Basically you controller method should be populating the `products` property - e.g. `searchModel.products = _Repository.GetFilteredProducts(searchModel);` and then `return View(searchModel);` and you really only need one method and then change your form to `@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "yourControllerName", FormMethod.Get))`

Comment: Thanks that fixed it! I made the update in the model but forgot in the action/controller, so I was missing the update `filter.products = filteredProdList ;`.  Can you tell me how to append the async partialview results as HTML table, I cannot get it work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162646/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-transformer).

Comment: @StephenMuecke I can mark as answer, just post a one line text as answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to modify your `SearchModel` to include a collection property for the products

```
public class SearchModel
{
    public int? PriceFrom { get; set; }
    public int? PriceTo { get; set; }
    ....
    public IEnumerable<ProductVM> Products { get; set; } // add
}
```

then you return just `SearchModel` to your view

```
public ActionResult Filter(SearchModel filter)
{
    filter.Products = _repository.GetFilteredProducts(filter);
    return View(filter);
}
```

and your view will be

```
@model SearchModel
....
@using (Html.BeginForm("Filter", "yourControllerName", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PriceFrom)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.PriceFrom)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PriceFrom)
    ... // other form controls for properties you want to filter the results on
    <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
}
@Html.Partial("_ResultsPartialView", Model.Products)
```