# Ajax to MVC POST request: Redirection issue, "Page not working"

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, http-post, asp.net-ajax

I am having a tiny issue after my Post request (from AJAX to the controller). Basically,  the post request takes place, it executes the function in the controller, **however**, after it executes the ajax call, I get the following page:
[image]

I don't know why that is happening, and I would appreciate some help. I haven't worked with this kind of stuff before.
Here are some code snippets that can help:

**EDITED** **.js** file:

```
    function Export() {
   

    var donations = new Array();
    $("#Donations tbody tr").each(function () {
        var row = $(this);
        var donation = {};
        donation.Name = row.find("td").eq(0)[0].innerText;
        donation.DOB = row.find("td").eq(1)[0].innerText;
        donation.DOD = row.find("td").eq(2)[0].innerText;
        donation.COD = row.find("td").eq(3)[0].innerText;
        donation.CaseNumber = row.find("td").eq(4)[0].innerText;
        donations.push(donation);
    });

    
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Donation/Export",
        data: JSON.stringify(donations),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("file saved: ", data);            
        }
    }).done(function () {
        window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Download", "DonationController", new { csv = data }))';
    });;
};
```

**EDITED** Index.cshtml:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    <p>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" value="Export" onclick="Export()" />

    </p>


    <table id="Donations" class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Full Name</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Person.DateOfBirth)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Donation.DateOfDeath)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Donation.CauseOfDeath)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Donation.CaseNumber)</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model.Donations)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td><a asp-action="Details" asp-controller="Person" asp-route-id="@item.PersonId">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Person.Title) @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Person.Forenames) @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Person.Surname)</a></td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Person.DateOfBirth)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateOfDeath)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CauseOfDeath)</td>
                    <td><a asp-action="Details" asp-controller="Donation" asp-route-id="@item.PersonId">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CaseNumber)</a></td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
```

**EDITED** DonationController.cs:

```
[HttpPost]
        public string Export()
       
        {
                    
            var resolveRequest = HttpContext.Request;         
           
            string[] columnNames = { "Name", "DOB","DateOfDeath", "CauseOfDeath", "CaseNumber" };

            //Build the CSV file data as a Comma separated string.
            string csv = string.Empty;

            foreach (string columnName in columnNames)
            {
                //Add the Header row for CSV file.
                csv += columnName + ',';
            }

            //Add new line.
            csv += "\r\n";

            foreach (string k in resolveRequest.Form.Keys)
            {
                using JsonDocument doc = JsonDocument.Parse(k);
                JsonElement root = doc.RootElement;;
                var users = root.EnumerateArray();

                while (users.MoveNext())
                {
                    var user = users.Current;
                    var props = user.EnumerateObject();

                    while (props.MoveNext())
                    {
                        var prop = props.Current;                        
                        csv += String.IsNullOrEmpty(prop.Value.ToString()) ? "," : prop.Value.ToString().Replace(",", ";") + ',';
                        //Console.WriteLine($"{prop.Name}: {prop.Value}");
                    }
                    csv += "\r\n";
                }

                
            }           
            
            
            return (csv);
            
            
        }

        public FileContentResult Download(string csv)
        {
            //Download the CSV file.
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(csv);
            return File(bytes, "application/text", "Donations.csv");
           
    }
```

Comment: Did you try `[FromForm]` instead of using `[FromBody]` in your controller? But already controller must know data that comes from view and it can handle.What is your main problem : dont reach to controller with Ajax post request? Or redirect problem after getting data from post? @HK1232

Comment: @Gökhan Aldanmaz The problem is the latter, a redirect issue after getting data from post. Basically, as soon as I click the Export button, the ajax post call is made, then it goes to Export function in the controller, and that's when I get the 415 error (even before it reaches the return statement -im debugging-).
I just tried the [FromForm] instead but the data posted is now null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File cannot be passed as a querystring, which will cause the payload format is in an unsupported format. This will result in a [415 error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/415).

In your `Export` method(`IActionResult,return a Jsonresult`):

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Export([FromBody] List<ExportedValues> values)
    {
      //...
      return new JsonResult (new {csv = csv });
    }
```

Then in your `Download` method:

```
 public FileContentResult Download(string csv)
   {
       return File(//Convert to your file)
   }
```

In your ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Donation/Export",
    data: JSON.stringify(donations),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
                console.log("file saved: ", data);
                window.location = '/Donation/Download?csv=' + data.csv;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the feedback. I updated my code as you suggested, however I am still getting the 415 error. Basically, as soon as I click the Export button, the ajax post call is made, then it goes to Export function in the controller, and that's when I get the 415 error (even before it reaches the return statement of Export). 
So with what you're suggesting, would I then call the Download function in onsuccess from ajax?

Comment: I edited my code in the post, and I don't get the 415 error anymore so that's great! But I am probably doing something wrong with regards to calling the Download function, because it's not going there after the csv string is returned in Export. Any idea what could be wrong? Thanks again I appreciate your help. And sorry if these are basic questions, I haven't done much work with this at all. Thanks

Comment: Hi @HK1232,I have updated my answer,you can check it.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! I tweaked a few and added your changes to my code and it works perfectly. Thanks again for being so responsive!